# How to make sure/test that unused gas line is safe?

Tags: natural-gas

I have an existing gas line that runs underground to my patio. The line has been disconnected at some point so it’s only a pipe.

Since I want to place a BBQ on my patio, I’d like to re-activate this line.

What are the concerns for safety?
How can I make sure that using this pipe is safe?

Comment: I think the main test is to pressurize it.  You add air(think nitrogen is preferred) to about 15 pounds and leave it for more than 24 hours.  This assumes both ends were capped/sealed.  If the pipe was left open for years, it might be better to use new pipe.

Comment: I think it might have been open but I don’t know the history. A new pipe would be a HUGE project because it runs under the patio, lawn etc

Comment: Should blow the pipe out, if possible, then the pressure test.  You do want to make sure nothing is in the pipe to cause problems/blockages.

Comment: Definitely have the pipe flushed out, then pressure tested.

Comment: The ends of the pipe are accessible at the patio and in your house?

Comment: After pressure testing the system branch with it separate from your operating system, then there's a noncorrosive liquid used to check the work subsequently installed to bridge the new branch to your operating system. Basically a "soapy water test."

Answer (score 1):

There aren't many times that I'll suggest calling a pro over DIY, but this is one of them.

- Call the gas company - they might even test it for free.
- My HVAC guy is licensed to install gas line, I'm sure he'd also be able to test an existing line to ensure it's safe to use.
- I would think that some plumbers are also licensed to install gas lines.

My reasoning for calling in a pro:

- Yes, electrical work can be dangerous and you can start a fire.

  - There are many protections in place (like circuit breakers) to help prevent that.
  - It's easy to visually review your work *before* turning on a breaker to double & triple check that you've got it right.
- Gas fittings can *look* right, but be wrong.

  - Yes, you can smell gas escaping, but by then it might be too late.
  - In this particular instance, there could be damage inside buried pipe. Turning the gas on could lead to gas escaping underground and eventually working its way to the surface where it becomes a danger days/weeks/months later in the middle of the night.
- An electrical fire generally will only damage one residence.
- A gas explosion can level a neighborhood affecting *many* families, not just one.

Call around until you find someone licensed and willing to test. Be willing to pay them if the test comes back indicating repair is necessary. If one guy says repair is necessary, it may be worth getting a second opinion (and quote).

Answer (score 1):

> I have an existing gas line that runs underground to my patio. The line has been disconnected at some point so it’s only a pipe.

In what way was it disconnected?

- Was it merely shut off using a valve within the house?
- Was it disconnected and capped?
- Was the line completely torn out of the house?

Knowing these answers would allow use to provide a better sense of scope and cost.

I'd estimate $300-$1000.

If the existing line has to be replaced then $2000+ wouldn't surprise me.

---

> Since I want to place a BBQ on my patio, I’d like to re-activate this line.

Excellent. I've loved grilling ever since running natural gas to my grill. No more fear of running out of the silly 20 LB tank!

---

> What are the concerns for safety?

The consequences aren't tiered. House explosion could be the only warning you get. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q46UsKIxQpQ

Realistically, it depends on your skill level and due diligence. Based on your question wording, I'd say you should hire a licensed plumber to assess the situation and give you a quote.

---

> How can I make sure that using this pipe is safe?

You, personally? Don't. This isn't average DIY territory.

The plumber will pressure test the existing line to check for leaks which could indicate a rotting pipe. They should check for any potential blockages. If they neglect to perform this test, proceed with the install, and then discover a leak then you'll have zero clue whether it's the existing pipe's fault or the new install.

After they get everything installed then they will pressure test their work again.

A permit might be required; I don't know, check your locale.

If pressure tests are not performed and you have a leak outside then your gas bill will skyrocket; albeit, you don't risk explosion unless the gas is sucked back into your home.

If there is a leak inside the home then the smell of gas would be quite evident.

Comment: Real BBQ don't use gas.

Comment: @crip659 take it up with OP, I used "grilling" in my answer for a reason =)